# "Top questions" list - show asker (and rep) as well as most recent activity?

Tags: feature-request, questions

On the "top questions" list on the front page of a SE site, I would like to see the name of the asker (and their rep) as well as the name of the contributor with the most recent activity on this question.

Would there be any wider support for this?

Comment: What would be the advantages?

Comment: @jzd: Well, personally I treat questions differently depending on whether I "know" (recognise) the asker or not, and the rep of the asker. In general (not a guarantee of course), the higher the rep of the asker, the more likely the question is to be insightful or interesting (if it's new it may not have been voted up yet) and you are more likely to get an answer accepted. Similarly if looking for "easy rep" then answering newbie questions from askers with low rep might be a way to go for some people.

Comment: I understand.  In that case do you care who last contributed to the question?

Comment: @jzd: Actually, not so much. But I assumed that the reason that was there was because *someone* wanted it! :-)

Comment: Thinking more about it, actually I do use the last activity to judge whether there has been anything new since I last looked at the question. However, it doesn't seem to treat comments as new activity, so this is only partially useful.